# Angular 4 + firebase, output nested object in object

Tags: angular, firebase

My firebase:

```
 {
      "hotel" : {
        "-Kjgyamcup6ULm0Awa-1" : {
          "complete" : "true",
          "images" : {
            "-Kjgyb6A2gRiDhwaWx-V" : {
              "name" : "2.jpg",
              "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/teplo-31a17.appspot.com/o/hotel%2F-Kjgyamcup6ULm0Awa-1%2Fimages%2F2.jpg?alt=media&token=0faffb92-9bc5-44ce-9189-ee405137c3bf"
            },
            "-KjgybAKrkf3EzYxvgGD" : {
              "name" : "4.jpg",
              "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/teplo-31a17.appspot.com/o/hotel%2F-Kjgyamcup6ULm0Awa-1%2Fimages%2F4.jpg?alt=media&token=bd7ebc47-b14d-46e5-a58d-01d647fcf95d"
            }
          },
          "number" : "102",
          "price" : "2500"
        }, etc
```

How i can output images?
my code in component.ts

```
 export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

 hotelNumbers: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) { 

    this.hotelNumbers = af.database.list('/hotel');

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


}
```

and html

```
<div *ngFor="let hotel of hotelNumbers | async">
  <p>{{hotel.number}}</p>
  etc
</div>
```

How output image  ( *ngFor="image of hotel.number.images | async" ) - no work

Comment: That is not the whole JSON? I mean there is nothing to iterate like you have in template. Could you show the actual JSON you are getting? It should be an Array.

Comment: http://pastenow.ru/bcf328ad23f52bea6eacdc5442b2e8ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could solve the problem as follows:

edit my database by advice rmekarni:

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJsfV.jpg)

edit component.ts file

```
 constructor(private af: AngularFire) { 

    this.hotelNumbers = af.database.list('/hotel').map((myhotels) =>{
      return myhotels.map(myhotel =>{
        myhotel.img = af.database.list('/images/' + myhotel.$key);
        return myhotel;   
      });
    });

  }
```

edit html file

```
<div *ngFor="let myhotel of hotels | async">
  <p>{{myhotel.number}}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let img of myhotel.img | async">
      <img src="{{img.url}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.hotels = af.database.list('/hotel');`

Firebase is wonderful because it merges an observable with an array. So you can consider the observable returned by `af.database.list('/hotel')` like an array, and do a ngFor with an async pipe on it :

```
<div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels | async">
  <p>{{hotel.images}}</p>
  etc
</div>
```

it's because `hotel` is an item (a key in your JSON object) and it has got the `images` attribute (price, complete, etc.)

If you want to iterate on the images of all hotels, then your datastructure is wrong. You should denormalize it and make flatten data structures. Here an excellent article about it, you must read it !
[Firebase doc - structure your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

If you really want to keep that data structure, then you can't iterate the images directly with the async pipe. You have yo subscribe to your hotels and get the images nested objects with a callback. And I think you'll have to make an array by iterate your nested json with `Object.keys(json).forEach(key => json[key]...);` and then use the array in the ngFor directive...